# Badge value of a standard push payload gets ignored when app is registered for Newsstand pushes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

From what it looks like, if my app is registered for UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability, iOS will not update my app's badge icon even if the push payload contains a non-zero badge value.  Is this expected behavior for apps that register for newsstand pushes?  I can't find any Apple documentation to support this, so I was curious if others have seen this as well.

If I remove UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability from list of accepted remote notifications, then the setting of badge works fine.

Comment: I can confirm that this doesn't work with the UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability. If I removed that the badge would set. :(